# Call method from object from a class inherits from another class

Tags: c++

I'am novice in C++ and I don't understand how headers, class, object and inheritance work.

So I've problem in my code. I can't call my method **attack** from class Mage inherit from class Character.

When i try to test happen this error:

```
CMakeFiles\GUi.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/Guilherme/Dropbox/Develop/c++/t/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `Mage::attack()'
```

I really don't know where the problem. If someone can help me i'll be glad.

**This main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "chars/Mage.h"

int main() {
    Mage myChar;
    myChar.attack();
    return 0;
}
```

**Mage.h**

```
class Mage{
public:
    void attack();
};
```

**Mage.cpp**

```
#include "Character.h"

class Mage : public Character{
public:
    double maxHP = 20;
    void attack(){

    }
};
```

**Character.h**

```
#define MINIMUM_POINTS 1
#define STATUS_CHARACTER_DEAD false
#define STATUS_CHARACTER_LIVED true
#include <string.h>

class Character{

public:
    Character();

    int level; //current level

    double maxHP; //Max Life

    double maxMP; //Max points to use mana

    double attackPhysical; //Power physical attack

    double attackMagic; // Points to magic attack

    double defensePoints; // Point to physical attack defense

//    string name; //Char name

    bool live; // if person is live or dead



    void setName(); //Setter Char name

    void getName(); //Getter char name

    void attack();
};
```

**Character.cpp*

```
class Character{
public:
    void attack(){

    };
};
```

Comment: Not sure if it's your issue, but you're violating the one-definition rule. You should put the entire declaration of the class in the header, and only put the implementations in your source files.

Comment: I understand the problem. First, the compiler wasn't complite Character.cpp, and Mage.cpp.

Comment: After that i only need adjust in file Mage.cpp, Character.cpp to import file Mage.h and Character.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have just one definition of the 'class Mage'. You have two and they contradict each other. One is in Mage.h and the other in Mage.cpp. You should have only the implementation of Mage::attack in Mage.cpp in this way:

```
void Mage::attack(){

}
```

Also you do need to understand how header files work in C/C++ before anything else.

Answer (score 1):

In Mage.cpp:

```
void Mage::attack(){

}
```

also in Character.cpp:

```
void Character::attack(){

};
```